# Find and copy file based on a csv input list - Powershell or python

Tags: python, powershell

I have many directories that to find copy files from a list that i provide in a csv format. The csv file would be something like

```
File_A.log,RED
File_B.log,BlUE
File_C.log,RED
File_D.log,RED
File_E.log,BLUE
```

File_A.log,File_B.log,File_C.log and File_D.log are the file names that I will be searching for in the many folders directories that has a standard structure of "/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/"

RED and BLUE is the folder where I want to copy the found file i.e /BLUE and /RED

How can I achieve this in the most efficient way using either powershell or python

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the most efficient way".  Are you talking about minizing machine resource usage?  Or about shortest run time?  Or about labor effort needed for initial development?  Or about labor effort on an ongoing basis?

Comment: Show us what you already have tried **yourself**, what failed and what worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. im new to stack overflow. il do more research